# dispatch_failed with slash command in slack-go/socketmode and delay in response > 2 second

Tags: go, slack, slack-api

I am seeing dispatch_failed error with golang slack api https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/slack-go/slack when using socketmode.
This is when responding to a slash command. If the return is > 2 seconds, i get the dispatch_failed. If it is 2 seconds or less, there is no error.

sample code: (parts obfuscated, but this just responds to the slash command after a delay equal to the argument of the slash command)

Question: Is it possible to configurate the delay that slack errors for response with dispatch_failed in the golang slack api? I am not able to find an option.

```
    client := socketmode.New(
        api,
        socketmode.OptionDebug(true),
        socketmode.OptionLog(log.New(os.Stdout, "socket: ",
            log.Lshortfile|log.LstdFlags)),
    )


    for e := range client.Events {
    ...
       switch e.Type{
         case socketmode.EventTypeSlashCommand:
            cmd, _ := e.Data.(slack.SlashCommand)
    
            switch cmd.Command {
            ...
            case "/dispatchFailureLatencyTest":
                t := time.Now()
                log.Printf("testing effect of delay")
                d,err  := strconv.Atoi(strings.Split(cmd.Text, " ")[0])
                if err != nil {
                    i = 2 // default 2 seconds if failure getting arg
                }
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(d) * time.Second)
                ret = fmt.Sprintf("waited for %d seconds", d)
                log.Printf("elapsed: %v\n", time.Now().Sub(t))
            }
     ...
                payload := map[string]interface{}{
                    "blocks": []slack.Block{
                        slack.NewSectionBlock(
                            &slack.TextBlockObject{
                                Type: slack.MarkdownType,
                                Text: ret,
                            },
                            nil, nil,
                        ),
                    }}
                client.Ack(*e.Request, payload)
     }
  ...

 }
```